# Launching VxSim from Workbench 3.3

Tags: vxworks

I am having problem connecting to a VxSim target. I am using WR Workbench 3.3 on Windows 8.1.

The error I am getting is "The VxWorks simulator telnet port didn't get available in 5 seconds...".
Trying to follow a suggestion to change the LOCAL_MEM_LOCAL_ADRS didn't help.

Please advise.

Daniel

Comment: I think you should be able to literally TELNET into that IP/PORT address combination. Try that and see what happens. Then start to debug backwards. It could be as simple as opening up Windows Firewall.